# Impossible to restrict access to S3 folder in Sagemaker Canvas

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio, aws-iam-policy

I'm creating an app where you can create an organization, invite people to join it and end up using Sagemaker Studio, and therefore Canvas. Everything works perfectly until I want users to only be able to access their organization's folder to import data and create datasets. Each organization's folder looks like this: "bucket-name/ULID" (ULID being the organization's id). As a first step, I recreate the SagemakerFullAccess policy, removing the "ListBucket" action, which lists all bucket's folders, in order to customize it. I then create a policy for my sagemaker execution role so that users only have access to their folders. I also create a policy for my users so that they can only add, get and delete objects in their folders. Here are the two policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Restrict access to org folder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix":"${aws:PrincipalTag/org_id}/*"          // "01HPHA50JHJVJZTVMEEF2HLPQZV/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Restrict access to org folder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/${aws:PrincipalTag/org_id}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

From what I've seen across lots of forums, this is the right way to restrict a user to a folder, however when I use it here, I don't have access to the folder.

[image: Error]
I've tried a lot of things:

Change the resource to "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/ULID".
Change the s3 prefix to:
directly the ULID,
by another folder,
"ULID",
"ULID/",
"ULID",
"/ULID",
.... The only time there was no error was when I used "*", everything is displayed but it's not what I want. I suspect Sagemaker Canvas is not very permissive, either display everything or nothing, it's already the same with buckets listing: either everything or nothing.
If anyone could help me with this problem, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I think Canvas might just be using ListBucket to list all the buckets, so you're seeing all the buckets. Are you able to restrict import of datasets? Is the expectation that Canvas only lists specific buckets and not all?

Comment: ListBucket is used to list all the data inside a bucket, and ListAllMyBuckets is used to list all the buckets. And no I can't restrict the import of datasets and that's what I'm trying to do. I want it to be restricted by folder.